# Reverse of Apply on built-in functions

Tags: functions

So if I have can use Apply and Or in combination:

```
Or @@ {a, b, c, d}
```

Out:

```
a || b || c || d
```

One could also use Or[a, b, c, d], but we'll ignore it for the sake of the main question.

Is there an inverse operation for this? Such that

```
SplitBy[a || b || c || d, OrSplit]
```

Out:

```
{a, b, c, d}
```

Coz I really, really don't want to keep manipulating Strings to break these expressions -- (in)equalities and logical and set union/disjoints.

Comment: `List @@ (* expression *)` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Hah... Silly me.. That works. Just want you to know I appreciate all the help. Just saying as in less than an hour I will delete this post.

Comment: Well, somebody else answered already. Can't delete it now.

Answer (score 6):

As Guess says, `List @@ expr` should work.

A weirder way: `First@Replace[{a || b || c || d}, Or -> List, {2}, Heads -> True]`

A less weird way: `ReplacePart[a || b || c || d, 0 -> List]`